# Showing that it is not possible that for every $q_j$ it holds that $2+\prod_{k \neq j} q_k $ is divisible by $q_j$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, integers

Let $n\ge 1$ and let $Q= \{q_1,\cdot\cdot, q_n\}$ be a set of $n$ odd primes, all different and such that  $Q \neq \{3\}$.

> Show that there is no set $Q$ such that for every $q_j$ it holds that
> $2+\prod_{k \neq j} q_k $ is divisible by $q_j$.

(With the convention that an empty product is $1$.)

Clearly this is true when $n=1$ since in this case, $q_1 \neq 3$.

This is also true for $n=2$ since if $q_1 \lt q_2$ and $q_1$ divides $q_2+2$, it is not possible that $q_2$ divides $q_1+2$.

For $n=3$, this is shown as follows: suppose that there exist three odd primes $p\lt q \lt r$ such that $3\le p \lt q$ and $r\ge 7$ such that $p$ divides $q\cdot r +2$, $q$ divides $p\cdot r +2$ and $r$ divides $p\cdot q +2$, then $p\cdot q$ divides $p\cdot q \cdot r^2 +4 +2r(p+q)$, then there exists $K$ such that $K\cdot p\cdot q=1+r\frac{p+q}{2}$. But $ \frac{1}{p\cdot q}+ \frac{r}{2q}+ \frac{r}{2p} \le \frac{1}{15}+ \frac{r}{10}+ \frac{r}{6}= \frac{1+4r}{15}$.
Then $ 1 +r\frac{p+q}{2} \le \frac{1+4r}{15} p\cdot q$ , then $K \le \frac{1+4r}{15}$.  On the other hand, $r$ divides $p\cdot q +2$ then $r$ divides $K\cdot p\cdot q+ 2K= 2K+1 + r\frac{p+q}{2}$, then $r$ divides $2K+1 \le  \frac{17+8r}{15}$ then $7r \le 17 $ which contradicts $r\ge7$.

It can be shown that a similar proof (showing a contradiction on the size of the largest member of $Q$) works as long as $n\le 8$. The case $n=9$ does not bring a contradiction but a finite limit ($958$) to the size of the largest member of $Q$, then the case $n=9$ can be settled by checking a large but finite number of cases.  Hence, should such a set $Q$ exist, it has to contain at least $10$ different prime numbers. Similarly, this method shows that if $3$ is not allowed, $Q$ must contain at least $28$ different prime numbers.

For the context, I have found that a proof of the above statement for any $n$  would imply that the conjecture raised in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4273287/130022) is true.

I would also accept as an answer a disproof of the above claim or the exhibition of such a set $Q$.

Moreover, as explained in @acreativename answer, we know that

> For all $n \gt 1$, there exist infinitely many non-empty sets $Q_n$ of $n$ odd primes $q_1 \lt q_2, \cdot\cdot, \lt q_n$  such that for all $j \lt n$ it holds that
> $2+\prod_{k \neq j} q_k $ is divisible by $q_j$.

$Q_6= \{\color{red}{3,5,7,13,23},3697 \}$ is an example for $n=6$:

$$3697\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13+2= \color{red}{23}\cdot219409$$
$$3697\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot23+2= \color{red}{13}\cdot686789$$
$$3697\cdot3\cdot5\cdot13\cdot23+2= \color{red}{7}\cdot443\cdot5347$$
$$3697\cdot3\cdot7\cdot13\cdot23+2= \color{red}{5}\cdot11\cdot422063$$
$$3697\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13\cdot23+2= \color{red}{3}\cdot71\cdot181639$$
but as $n$ increases, finding such $Q_n$ by brute force becomes increasingly difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Your second question can be proven to be true when one uses Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression. Let $q_{1}, q_{2}, ..., q_{n-1}$ be any distinct odd primes. Choosing any prime $p>q_{n-1}$ that satisfies the $n-1$ congruences

$j)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }2 + p\prod_{k =1, k \neq j}^{n-1}q_{k} \equiv 0 \mod(q_{j})$

for $j = 1,...,n-1$ and setting $p = q_{n}$ solves the lemma. Note that here we used the Chinese remainder theorem; the above system of modular equations has a unique solution modulo $q_{1}q_{2}...q_{n-1}$ that is necessarily coprime to each $q_{j}$. Later we applied Dirichlet's theorem which tells us that any arithmetic sequence $an+b$ with $(a,b) = 1$ contains infinitely many primes.

Comment: you apply the Chinese remainder theorem with the $n-1$ congruences $2\cdot s_j +x \equiv 0 \bmod q_j$ , $s_j $ being the modular inverse of $\prod _{k=1, k\neq j}^{n-1}q_k$ in $\mathbb{Z} {/q_j\mathbb{Z}}$, right? Then, by Dirichlet we know that there are infinitely many $x$ which are prime. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes that is correct.